# which fails to find command in path

Tags: bash

I have a program called `f` in my `$PATH`, I can simply execute it by typing `f` into a terminal. However, typing `which f` into that same terminal afterwards, it errors out: `which: no f in (...)`, and it gives the full path in brackets (which indeed contains the correct path for `f` itself).

Using `type f` however I get the correct result.

Does anyone have an idea why that is the case?

---

Here are the answers to questions from the comments:

- f itself is a symlink to a perl script:

  ```
  vwos3xz@vwososuvs012:~$ls -l $(command -v f)

  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42  2. Aug 2012  /tef/tegf/06_CAE_System/064_soft/PERL_SCRIPTE/bin/f -> ../CRASH_SCRIPTE/FEMSTARTER/fem-starter.pl
  ```

  In fact, fem_starter.pl itself is a symlink to fem_starter-1.77.pl in the same directory
- I'm reasonably sure there's no typo in the path because I can simply type `f` in a terminal and have it run (also, type and command -v work).
- I set the path in .bashrc, but .bash_profile exists and just sources .bashrc. Also, I have BASH_ENV set to my .bashrc.
- `type f` returns `f ist /tef/tegf/06_CAE_System/064_soft/PERL_SCRIPTE/bin/f`, and `command -v` returns `/tef/tegf/06_CAE_System/064_soft/PERL_SCRIPTE/bin/f`. Also, `type -a f` returns the same as `type f`.
- "Have you opened a new window?"... do you mean a new terminal? I did, but that did not make a difference. I used both xterm and konsole, and I did start each from the window manager as well as from another xterm. Everytime, the $PATH was correctly set, but which did not work as expected.

Comment: Try `type which`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/677212/2908724

Comment: It's  surprising that which is not a builtin, as I simply assumed. Also, which not doing what it should is surprising. Do you have any idea why that's the cause? I have weird path issues to sort out, and that's sort of the only lead I have...

Comment: What OS (`uname -a`)? What is the result of `type which`? Please show the full output of all commands you've tried.

Comment: Without more information, the best we can do is close this as a duplicate of SO 677212.  What type of command is `f`?  Where is it stored?  Are you sure there isn't a typo in your PATH?  What is the correct result?  Can you make an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))?  I recognize that in this case, it may be hard to create an operational MCVE.  Have you tried creating a new window?  Do you set your PATH in your `.profile` (`.bash_profile`) or in `.bashrc`?  What does `type f` say?  What does `command -v f` say?

Comment: What does `type -a f which` say?

Comment: @PhilippFrank _which not doing what it should is surprising._ It's surprising to me that `which` is so popular, given that it is not (and never has been) part of any standard, unlike [command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html), [type](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html) and [hash](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/hash.html). What I mean is, whatever is it that `which` _should do_, no standards body has ever agreed upon.

Comment: What filesystem is the perl file stored on?

Comment: Did you look at the file to see if there is a CRLF line ending?  'Command not found' can mean either the script itself, or the command nominated in the shebang line.